# Rest-assured POST call with multipart that contains Vietnamese characters in contentbody

Tags: java, rest-assured

I am sending POST call to an endpoint with a controlname's contentbody that contain Vietnamese character (such as `á` `ư`, `ồ`, `ự`..).

Although request was sent successfully, those special characters were replaced by `???` like `ch?a ???c n?` where it should be `chưa được nè` at UI :

[image: illlustration]

```
public class MakeCostObject {
    RequestSpecBuilder requestSpec;
    public MakeCostObject() {
        requestSpec = new RequestSpecBuilder();
        String note = "chưa được nè";
        String status = "init";

        requestSpec.addMultiPart("note", note);
        requestSpec.addMultiPart("status", status);
    }

    public RequestSpecification createCost() {
        public RequestSpecification createCost () {
            return requestSpec.build();
        }
    }
}
```

This is POST request, spec is created from `createCost` function.

```
response = given()
            .header("Content-type", "multipart/form-data")
            .header("Authorization", token)
            .when()
            .spec(spec)
            .post(APIPath.apiPath.POST_cost_upload);

response.then().assertThat().statusCode(201);
```

I tried another API (non form-data), and UI can display perfectly.

```
String str = "Tiếng việt";
Map<String, Object> body = new HashMap<>();

body.put("note", str);

given().spec(HeaderConfigs.headerwithnewToken())
        .when()
        .body(body)
        .patch("/costdetail/xxxx/");
```

How can I config to encode or something to solve my issue?

My io.rest-assured version : 4.2.0.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it in the console you see `ch?a` ? And your functionality is working fine ?

Comment: @WilfredClement Hi. First thing, our function worked well, I checked from UI. Second your console showed expected result, I mean it was correct. Third I double checked under PostMan, and it could send the string to server perfectly.

Comment: So what's the issue here then ?

Comment: @WilfredClement, it displayed in UI wrongly as my image which is a part of UI screen  :| I wonder, did I miss some config while I'm calling API request by rest-assured?

Comment: could you try content type `multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8` ?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue by myself. Just replace:

```
requestSpec.addMultiPart("note", note);
```

by

```
requestSpec.addMultiPart(new MultiPartSpecBuilder(note).controlName("note").charset(Charsets.UTF_8).build());
```